# Confused about some questions in my exam!

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know the solution for these questions.

1- People who ...... shops should be punished. ( plunder - takeaway ) 
2- Ice boxes are useful because they keep goods ....... . ( good condition - fresh )

:- My openion :
I choosed : takeaway - fresh 
The reason why I choosed "fresh" is that "good condition" show come after "in".
Sorry if my question avoids the rules, if so it could be removed or closesd!

Comment: What exactly is the question ? Are we to replace the blanks with any word or has it got to do something to do with the ones in the brackets ??

Comment: The question is choose from the correct answer, but it's already answered, thanks!

Comment: **plunder** is an old-fashioned word in this context. The contemporary verb is **loot**. Also, **ice-box** is old-fashioned. The contemporary noun is **fridge** or **refrigerator**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is

> People who **plunder** shops should be punished

To **plunder** is to rob or steal things.  Your thought of **takeaway** is along the right lines since things are **being taken away**, but

> People who **takeaway** shops

would be people who steal the **entire** shop, not just what's inside (if they do, they really should be punished!)

> Ice boxes are useful because they keep goods **fresh**
>   Ice boxes are useful because they keep goods **in good condition**

**Fresh** is the correct answer and your sense of using **in** with **good condition** is also correct.

Comment: Well, I am disappointed now! 1 mistake overall. But thanks alot!

Comment: You were on the right track (I think), keep studying!

Comment: The problem I never heard of verb "plunder", But i though of the same explanation you gave about verb "takeaway" so I was about to choose "plunder" but i reverted!

Comment: **Plunder and pillage** can be found [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Pillage+and+Plunder). It is usually good practice to **upvote** answers you think have good points and **accept** answers which completely answer your question. Welcome to ELL!

Comment: I was voting while it said that I can't vote until I get 15 rep!!

Comment: "Takeaway" as one word is not a verb but an adjective. You could say, "This is a takeaway meal", meaning it is a meal that you will eat somewhere other than the store. You could say a place is a "takeaway shop", meaning it is a shop that sells things to be consumed elsewhere (presumably things of a type normally consumed on premises, or we wouldn't need to say). But you can't "takeaway a shop". You could "take away a shop", if you literally picked up the shop and carried it somewhere. That seems unlikely, but you might say, "I saw a tornado take away the shop."